# Assigning attributes to a list of graphs

Tags: r, attributes, igraph, lapply

I have created a list of graphs and now I want to assign the same weight to all edges in all graphs in my list. I know I can do it using a simple loop:

```
for (i in 1:5) E(graph_dat[[i]])$weight <- 1
```

but I am wondering if there is a way of doing it using the `lapply` function? (I am working with the `igraph` package.)

**EDIT:** 
Here is a reproducible example:

```
graph_dat <- list()
for (i in 1:3) graph_dat[[i]] <- erdos.renyi.game(i+3, 1/5, directed = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: For your example, `lapply(1:3, erdos.renyi.game, p.or.m=1/5, directed=TRUE)`. 

For setting edgeweights, `graph_dat1 <- lapply(graph_dat, function(x){E(x)$weight <- 1; return(x)})`

Sorry this is the 3rd edit. Answering too quickly for my own good.

Comment: I see! So whenever I want to act on elements within a list with something more complicated than `mean` I should just do it using a simple function like that? That makes so much sense! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered in a comment by Tad Dallas. To set edgeweights for all graphs within a function one can use `lapply` as follows:

```
lapply(graph_dat, function(x){E(x)$weight <- 1; return(x)})
```

I am copying his answer here so that I can mark my question as answered.